# how to reslove given error in spinnakers ?spinnaker deployed on kubernetes,and 8084 and 9000 are ports i gave. error came on hal deploy connect

Tags: kubernetes, spinnaker-halyard

```
Unable to listen on port 8084: All listeners failed to create with the follow           ing errors: Unable to create listener: Error listen tcp4 127.0.0.1:8084: bind           : address already in use, Unable to create listener: Error listen tcp6 [::1]:           8084: bind: cannot assign requested address
error: Unable to listen on any of the requested ports: [{8084 8084}]
Unable to listen on port 9000: All listeners failed to create with the follow           ing errors: Unable to create listener: Error listen tcp4 127.0.0.1:9000: bind           : address already in use, Unable to create listener: Error listen tcp6 [::1]:           9000: bind: cannot assign requested address
error: Unable to listen on any of the requested ports: [{9000 9000}]
! ERROR Error encountered running script. See above output for more
  details.
```

Comment: please share yaml file. this is not proper information

Answer (score 1):

I think it's port issue used by some another process please share your yaml file with more information.

Here sharing reference file

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: spinnaker

---

apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: spinnaker-admin
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: cluster-admin
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: default
  namespace: spinnaker

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: halyard-pv-claim
  namespace: spinnaker
  labels:
    app: halyard-storage-claim
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 10Gi
  storageClassName: standard

---

apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: spin-halyard
  namespace: spinnaker
  labels:
    app: spin
    stack: halyard
spec:
  replicas: 1
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: spin
      stack: halyard
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: spin
        stack: halyard
    spec:
      securityContext:
        runAsGroup: 1000
        fsGroup: 1000
      containers:
      - name: halyard-daemon
        # todo - make :stable or digest of :stable
        image: gcr.io/spinnaker-marketplace/halyard:stable
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        command:
        - /bin/sh
        args:
        - -c
        # We persist the files on a PersistentVolume. To have sane defaults,
        # we initialise those files from a ConfigMap if they don't already exist.
        - "test -f /home/spinnaker/.hal/config || cp -R /home/spinnaker/staging/.hal/. /home/spinnaker/.hal/ && /opt/halyard/bin/halyard"
        readinessProbe:
          exec:
            command:
            - wget
            - -q
            - --spider
            - http://localhost:8064/health
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8064
        volumeMounts:
        - name: persistentconfig
          mountPath: /home/spinnaker/.hal
        - name: halconfig
          mountPath: /home/spinnaker/staging/.hal/config
          subPath: config
        - name: halconfig
          mountPath: /home/spinnaker/staging/.hal/default/service-settings/deck.yml
          subPath: deck.yml
        - name: halconfig
          mountPath: /home/spinnaker/staging/.hal/default/service-settings/gate.yml
          subPath: gate.yml
        - name: halconfig
          mountPath: /home/spinnaker/staging/.hal/default/service-settings/igor.yml
          subPath: igor.yml
        - name: halconfig
          mountPath: /home/spinnaker/staging/.hal/default/service-settings/fiat.yml
          subPath: fiat.yml
        - name: halconfig
          mountPath: /home/spinnaker/staging/.hal/default/service-settings/redis.yml
          subPath: redis.yml
        - name: halconfig
          mountPath: /home/spinnaker/staging/.hal/default/profiles/front50-local.yml
          subPath: front50-local.yml
      volumes:
      - name: halconfig
        configMap:
          name: halconfig
      - name: persistentconfig
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: halyard-pv-claim
---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: spin-halyard
  namespace: spinnaker
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 8064
      targetPort: 8064
      protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: spin
    stack: halyard

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: halconfig
  namespace: spinnaker
data:
  igor.yml: |
    enabled: false
    skipLifeCycleManagement: true
  fiat.yml: |
    enabled: false
    skipLifeCycleManagement: true
  front50-local.yml: |
    spinnaker.s3.versioning: false
  gate.yml: |
    host: 0.0.0.0
  deck.yml: |
    host: 0.0.0.0
    env:
      API_HOST: http://spin-gate.spinnaker:8084
  redis.yml: |
    overrideBaseUrl: redis://spin-redis:6379
  config: |
    currentDeployment: default
    deploymentConfigurations:
    - name: default
      version: 1.12.2
      providers:
        appengine:
          enabled: false
          accounts: []
        aws:
          enabled: false
          accounts: []
          defaultKeyPairTemplate: '{{name}}-keypair'
          defaultRegions:
          - name: us-west-2
          defaults:
            iamRole: BaseIAMRole
        azure:
          enabled: false
          accounts: []
          bakeryDefaults:
            templateFile: azure-linux.json
            baseImages: []
        dcos:
          enabled: false
          accounts: []
          clusters: []
        dockerRegistry:
          enabled: false
          accounts: []
        google:
          enabled: false
          accounts: []
          bakeryDefaults:
            templateFile: gce.json
            baseImages: []
            zone: us-central1-f
            network: default
            useInternalIp: false
        kubernetes:
          enabled: true
          accounts:
          - name: my-kubernetes-account
            requiredGroupMembership: []
            providerVersion: V2
            dockerRegistries: []
            configureImagePullSecrets: true
            serviceAccount: true
            namespaces: []
            omitNamespaces: []
            kinds: []
            omitKinds: []
            customResources: []
            oAuthScopes: []
          primaryAccount: my-kubernetes-account
        oraclebmcs:
          enabled: false
          accounts: []
      deploymentEnvironment:
        size: SMALL
        type: Distributed
        accountName: my-kubernetes-account
        updateVersions: true
        consul:
          enabled: false
        vault:
          enabled: false
        customSizing: {}
        gitConfig:
          upstreamUser: spinnaker
      persistentStorage:
        persistentStoreType: s3
        azs: {}
        gcs:
          rootFolder: front50
        redis: {}
        s3:
          bucket: spinnaker-artifacts
          rootFolder: front50
          endpoint: http://minio-service.spinnaker:9000
          accessKeyId: dont-use-this
          secretAccessKey: for-production
        oraclebmcs: {}
      features:
        auth: false
        fiat: false
        chaos: false
        entityTags: false
        jobs: false
        artifacts: true
      metricStores:
        datadog:
          enabled: false
        prometheus:
          enabled: false
          add_source_metalabels: true
        stackdriver:
          enabled: false
        period: 30
        enabled: false
      notifications:
        slack:
          enabled: false
      timezone: America/Los_Angeles
      ci:
        jenkins:
          enabled: false
          masters: []
        travis:
          enabled: false
          masters: []
      security:
        apiSecurity:
          ssl:
            enabled: false
          overrideBaseUrl: /gate
        uiSecurity:
          ssl:
            enabled: false
        authn:
          oauth2:
            enabled: false
            client: {}
            resource: {}
            userInfoMapping: {}
          saml:
            enabled: false
          ldap:
            enabled: false
          x509:
            enabled: false
          enabled: false
        authz:
          groupMembership:
            service: EXTERNAL
            google:
              roleProviderType: GOOGLE
            github:
              roleProviderType: GITHUB
            file:
              roleProviderType: FILE
          enabled: false
      artifacts:
        gcs:
          enabled: false
          accounts: []
        github:
          enabled: false
          accounts: []
        http:
          enabled: false
          accounts: []
      pubsub:
        google:
          enabled: false
          subscriptions: []
      canary:
        enabled: true
        serviceIntegrations:
        - name: google
          enabled: false
          accounts: []
          gcsEnabled: false
          stackdriverEnabled: false
        - name: prometheus
          enabled: false
          accounts: []
        - name: datadog
          enabled: false
          accounts: []
        - name: signalfx
          enabled: false
          accounts: []
        - name: newrelic
          enabled: false
          accounts: []
        - name: aws
          enabled: true
          accounts:
          - name: kayenta-minio
            bucket: spinnaker-artifacts
            rootFolder: kayenta
            endpoint: http://minio-service.spinnaker:9000
            accessKeyId: dont-use-this
            secretAccessKey: for-production
            supportedTypes:
            - CONFIGURATION_STORE
            - OBJECT_STORE
          s3Enabled: true
        reduxLoggerEnabled: true
        defaultJudge: NetflixACAJudge-v1.0
        stagesEnabled: true
        templatesEnabled: true
        showAllConfigsEnabled: true
---

apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: minio-pv-claim
  namespace: spinnaker
  labels:
    app: minio-storage-claim
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 10Gi
  storageClassName: standard

---

apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  # This name uniquely identifies the Deployment
  name: minio-deployment
  namespace: spinnaker
spec:
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: minio
    spec:
      volumes:
      - name: storage
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: minio-pv-claim
      containers:
      - name: minio
        image: minio/minio
        args:
        - server
        - /storage
        env:
        - name: MINIO_ACCESS_KEY
          value: "dont-use-this"
        - name: MINIO_SECRET_KEY
          value: "for-production"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9000
        volumeMounts:
        - name: storage
          mountPath: /storage

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: minio-service
  namespace: spinnaker
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 9000
      targetPort: 9000
      protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: minio

---

apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: hal-deploy-apply
  namespace: spinnaker
  labels:
    app: job
    stack: hal-deploy
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: job
        stack: hal-deploy
    spec:
      restartPolicy: OnFailure
      containers:
      - name: hal-deploy-apply
        # todo use a custom image
        image: gcr.io/spinnaker-marketplace/halyard:stable
        command:
        - /bin/sh
        args:
        - -c
        - "hal deploy apply --daemon-endpoint http://spin-halyard.spinnaker:8064"
```